# Probability Question about distributing elements into boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm stuck on a probability question:

A bakery has a special offer for its customers. Every bag of its
bread contains a coupon having one of the letters of the word
BREAD. By collecting all the letters of the word, a customer is rewarded
with a free bag of bread. Assuming that all the letters have the same
probability of appearing in a bag, what is the probability that a person who
buys 8 bags will get one for free.

I tried to come up with the following:

First, let's consider the distinguishable letters of the word "BREAD" as 5 distinguishable boxes. Clearly the total number of words is $|\Omega| = 5^8$ because every letter we get from each bag can go into any of the 5 boxes. That's our denominator.

Now, we find the numerator $(|A|)$. Let's allot 1 letter out of the 8 letters (from the bags) to each of the 5 boxes, i.e., every box now has 1 letter. Finally, we distribute the 3 remaining letters from the bags randomly to any of the 5 boxes (without exclusion), which is done in $\binom{5-1+3}{3}$ ways.
 The final result is  $P(A) = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|} = \frac{\binom{5-1+3}{3}}{5^8}$.

However, the answer key gives a different answer( $\approx 0.32256)$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can't use stars and bars, because those distributions aren't equally likely.  Surely it's more likely that you get one of each letter plus an extra B, R, and E that that you get $8$ B's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know about [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)?

These count the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets, represented as $S(n,k)$.

So, given $k$ coupons and $n$ drawings, we have $k^{n}$ possible outcomes, $S(n,k)$ ways of putting these into non-empty subsets, and $k!$ ways to arrange members of those subsets.

So, the probability becomes $k!\  S(n,k)/k^{n}$, so $5! \ S(8,5)/5^{8}$ = 1008/3125 ~0.32256

Comment: Ok so I get that you are partitioning a set of $n = 8$ distinguishable letters into $k = 5$ non-empty subsets, but why did you multiply the count by $k!$ ? We don't care about which letters are in which subsets. Did you do that because the denominator considers ordering too?

Comment: @icecream2727 - think of the $k$ subsets as representing each of the coupon types, where the first subset is type 1, second is type 2...

Each draw number is assigned to some subset. The Stirling number gives you how many ways this can happen with no empty subset. But we must take into account that the order of these subsets can be shuffled. That's the k! term.